# How can I force Google Maps to render to polylines mid-loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

I have a section of code where the user can toggle the visibility of a large set of polylines. To turn them off, I `setMap(null)`, which happens quickly. But turning them on via `setMap(map)` takes a long time. Is there a way to trigger Google to draw the lines that have been added before the loop is complete?

The code currently is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
polylines[i].setMap(map);
}
```

I want to add a line like `if (i % 100 == 99)` that would trigger a rendering of all the new lines added. How do I force the Google Maps API to do this?

Comment: By doing setMap(null) you erase all the polylines you have previously added in your for loop.

I would suggest to rather change the opacity of the polylines in order to toggle the visibility

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide processor time for rendering.  Break the loop into multiple pieces and use `setTimeout` to release the processor to do rendering between the pieces.